# Views with form depending of payment method

Tags: django

I have 2 types of payment and 3 types of products.

I have one form with selecting product and selecting pay method:

```
<form action="/order-form/{{product.id}}" method="get">      
    <select name="producttype">
          <option value="type1">Select one of option</option>
          <option value="type1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="type2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="type3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="radio" name="pay" value="bank" /> Bank <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="pay" value="paypal"/> PayPal
    <input type="submit" value="Next"  id="form_submit"/>
</form>
```

I need to have after sending this form, next views with form depending of payment method.
How to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You've got the value of `producttype` in your request.GET params, so just return the relevant form from your Next view.

Comment: You really should be using `POST` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 def my_view(request):
     ...
     if request.method == "POST":
         payment_method =  request.POST.get("pay", None)
         product_type = request.POST.get("producttype", None)
         if payment_method == "bank":
             ...
         elif payment_method == "paypal":
             ...
```

Comment: One thing, form is being submit as `GET`. Otherwise +1